# Can not create resource group on azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create a resource group on Azure and get the error

> ajaxExtended call failed

Any idea why and how I can fix it?

Comment: should you not be asking microsoft?   they are the company that run that website / Portal    they have a help section and you can contact them for support, they also have a community forum. asking why a third party system throws an error, on a programming board is going to get nothing but voted down

Comment: Hi Dave, thought I was. Help had a link here. lol